# Get WPF Window class name. C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window

I need to get string value from WPF Window class? For example I have an instance of MainWorkspace window class, and I want to get this "MainWorkspace" string. How to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string name = theWindow.GetType().Name;
```